# Using PHP's preg_match to see if a value matches a list of values

Tags: php

I want to see if a variable contains a value that matches one of a few values in a hard-coded list. I was using the following, but recently found that it has a flaw somewhere:

```
if (preg_match("/^(init)|(published)$/",$status)) {
    echo 'found';
} else {
    echo 'nope';
}
```

I find that if the variable $status contains the word "unpublished" there is still a match even though 'unpublished' is not in the list, supposedly because the word 'unpublished' contains the word 'published', but I thought the ^ and $ in the regular expression are supposed to force a match of the whole word. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Modify your pattern:

```
$pattern = "/^(init|published)$/";
$contain = "unpublished";

echo preg_match($pattern, $contain) ? 'found' : 'nope' ;
```

This pattern says our string must be `/^init$/` or `/^published$/`, meaning those particular strings from start to finish. So substrings cannot be matched under these constraints.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. That seems to work, although I'm not sure why the change of parens alters the meaning.

Comment: Think of it as order of operations.  `/^a|b$/` means "Match (the beginning of the string followed by `a`) OR (`b` followed by the end of the string)".  `/^(a|b)$/` means "match beginning of the string, followed by `a` or `b`, followed by the end of the string".

Answer (score 1):

In this case, regex are not the right tool to use.

Just put the words you want your candidate to be checked against in an array:

```
$list = array('init', 'published');
```

and then check:

```
if (in_array($status, $list)) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks Michele. Why is regex the wrong way? What makes using an array better?

Comment: Mostly because of speed. Regex are slow. Also, it is difficult to edit a very long regex like that when you'll add, for example, hundreds of words, while it is easy to just push them into an array. Finally, in this use case you don't really need the power of regex, since they are full words matchings.

Comment: If you need to add a lot of words in $list, then I would suggest putting the array sorted in the code and then using a binary search in it. It will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

`^` matches the beginning of a string.  `$` matches the end of a string.

However, regexes are not a magic bullet that need to get used at every opportunity.

In this case, the code you want is

```
if ( $status == 'init' || $status == 'published' )
```

If you are checking against a list of values, create an array based on those values and then check to see if the key exists in the array.

Comment: Thanks Andy. In on-off situations I would use the == syntax, but in my particular case I have many statuses that will go into the list, so the == would become long-winded in my opinion.

Comment: Understood about long-winded.  That's why you build an array of them and then check the array.  If you're matching exact strings, you don't want to use regexes.  Now, if you were matching `init_\d+` because you could have 'init_01', 'init_473', then a regex would make sense.